# What does Autorecovery do in Apache Pulsar?

Tags: apache-pulsar

What is the function of the Autorecovery process in Apache Pulsar? What are the risks if the process is not run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autorecovery process is actually to detect under replicated ledgers on bookkeepers. The description and functionalities (audit and replication worker) can be found at https://bookkeeper.apache.org/docs/4.5.0/admin/autorecovery/#autorecovery

If the autorecovery process is not running, you need a way to detect bookkeeper and ledger replication issue and then fix them manually. Bookkeeper provides cli to fix under replicated ledgers. Here is the manual recovery https://bookkeeper.apache.org/docs/4.5.0/admin/autorecovery/#manual-recovery